# Run Scala code in remote server with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, hadoop, intellij-idea, cloudera

I downloaded the Cloudera QuickStart VM and I want to run some code Scala. I've found in the Cloudera a [tutorial](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/developers/home/developer-admin-resources/get-started-with-hadoop-tutorial/exercise-3.html) to run scala code in shell.

Now I want to use an IDE (like IntilliJ IDEA) and connect to the server spark and run my code. I've found [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html) but it didn't work for me. I can not find the same interface as described.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Why did this not work for you? Can you explain the problems you encountered more thoroughly?

Comment: Thanks for very quick comment. This did not work for me because I couldn't find the "Open the Settings dialog box (File | Settings ), and then click Deployment.
Choose Tools | Deployment | Configuration on the main menu" As described.

Comment: what version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: @DimitrisJim: I use the version of 14.1.4 in linux

Comment: You are using the community version, correct?